# Change user from dbo to Azure managed identity? (confirm connection?)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

Essentially, I want to eliminate the need for an account to maintain the connection and use a system-assigned managed identity to maintain the connection.

I followed the steps for this tutorial from the Microsoft documentation - [Tutorial: Connect to SQL Database from .NET App Service without secrets using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-10)

After creating the system-assigned user identity, the documentation has me grant the basic permissions via:

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
GO
```

I can see the system-assigned user identity under my Database > Security > Users.

I want to run a SELECT statement from the managed identity in order to confirm the connection from my App Service to my SQL Database.

I've tried using altering Dbo to my managed identity, but that was just a shot in the dark because you can't alter Dbo.

```
ALTER USER [dbo] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[managed-identity]
```

I'm not very experienced with SQL or databases in general.

Am I missing something right in front of me. Do I need change from dbo to my managed identity in order to confirm my managed identity is maintaining the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have provisioned an Azure Active Directory administrator for your Azure SQL logical server as explained in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#provision-azure-ad-admin-sql-database), because you may have missed that part. Please read all sections related to access Azure SQL with identities on that same documentation I shared with you.

In addition, consider making use of the [MSI-Validator](https://github.com/vijaysaayi/MSI-Validator/tree/master) to help you troubleshoot issues with Managed Identity for Azure App Services. [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/managed-identity-for-azure-app-services/ba-p/1711597) you will find how to use it.

Comment: I do have a provisioned AD administrator. The first link does not work.

Comment: I fixed the first link. Hope it helps.